# Connect four multithread design - Homework

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I'm trying to make a connect four game sumulation.

The program should have three threads - player 1, player 2 and game controller.The game controller thread has the responsibility of transfering control from one player to the other, has to monitor if a thread takes more than 5 second to execute, check if there is a winner and so on.

The interface the player classes must implement is:

```
public interface Player extends Runnable { 
   public int nextMove(int otherPlayerLastMove); 
   public void gameOver();
}
```

The method `nextMove` return the number of the column the player puts his next token in, and takes as a paramether the number of the column the oposing player put his last token.

The method `gameOver` must be called from the `game controller` thread to indicate end of the game and releasing of all resources from the player.

I don't have a problem with implementing the logic of the game it self, but I'm faceing a problem design wise. I just can't put my mind on what classes do I need and how they should interact. The obvious classes are `PlayerImpl` and `GameController` - which I think should keep the table for the game ( a 2D char array) and implement the checking logic. Or do I need a third class which contains only the table and to which the other two have access?

The basic code is here:

```
public class GameController implements Runnable{

private static char [][] table;

private void initTable(){
    table = new char[6][7];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            table[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}

public void printTable(){
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private char checkWinner(){
    //check for horizontal line
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {            
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if ( table[i][j] != '*' && table[i][j+1] != '*' && table[i][j+2] != '*' && table[i][j+3] != '*' && 
                    table[i][j] == table [i][j+1] && table[i][j+1] == table[i][j+2] && table[i][j+2] == table[i][j+3])
                return table[i][j];
        }           
    }
    //check for vertical line
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if ( table[i][j] != '*' && table[i+1][j] != '*' && table[i+2][j] != '*' && table[i+3][j] != '*' && 
                    table[i][j] == table [i+1][j] && table[i+1][j] == table[i+2][j] && table[i+2][j] == table[i+3][j])
                return table[i][j];
        }
    }
    // left to right diagonals

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 3; j < 7; j++) {
            if ( table[i][j] != '*' && table[i+1][j-1] != '*' && table[i+2][j-2] != '*' && table[i+3][j-3] != '*' && 
                    table[i][j] == table [i+1][j-1] && table[i+1][j-1] == table[i+2][j-2] && table[i+2][j-2] == table[i+3][j-3])
                return table[i][j];
        }
    }

    // right to left diagonals

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 3; j >=0; j--) {
            if ( table[i][j] != '*' && table[i+1][j+1] != '*' && table[i+2][j+2] != '*' && table[i+3][j+3] != '*' && 
                    table[i][j] == table [i+1][j+1] && table[i+1][j+1] == table[i+2][j+2] && table[i+2][j+2] == table[i+3][j+3])
                return table[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

public void addToken(int column, char token){
    for (int i = table.length ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if(table[i][column] == '*'){
            table[i][column] = token;
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

So how would you make the design of such a problem? An explanation or just a UML diagram would be great. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The specificity and lack of utility of this question make me suspect this is a homework assignment. If so, please tag this question accordingly.

Comment: Look into FiniteStateMachine Or Behavoral tree models to design your problem. http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/223-finite-state-machines.html & http://aigamedev.com/open/article/bt-overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you have methods on your `Runnable` tells me you are kinda going for an actor model.

This just means conceptually, you have the players and a controller, all having their own thread (they are all "actors"), and communicate through sending messages. In your case, you are doing that by accepting method calls (`nextMove`, `gameOver`).

Here is something that gets your code closer to an actor pattern.

```
class User extends Runnable {
    int userId;
    Controller controller;
    Queue<Message> msgQueue;

    void nextMove(int whoMoved, int whatMove){
        msgQueue.offer(new NextMove(whoMoved, whatMove));
    }

    void gameOver(){
        msgQueue.offer(new GameOver());
    }

    run(){
        while(true){
            Message msg = msgQueue.poll();
            if(msg != null){
                // deal with it
                // Maybe send message to controller
                controller.nextMove(new NextMove(userId, 4));
            } else {
                // Do something else, like talking to user
                // sleep to avoid hogging CPU
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code has many problems (like that fact that it will scale terribly, abstraction not being great etc. etc.), but I hope it illustrates the approach. Typical real actor model implementation use green threads to tackle scalability and provide standardised way to send and receive messages (e.g. see Akka, Erlang).

Comment: I thought green threads were dropped after java 1.1. This seems confusing in an answer to a question with the java tag.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: I thought it was more important to touch on the concept, rather than giving an answer that tries to be practical on a specific platform seeing that this is a homework to learn about concurrency (hence the mention of Erlang, for example).